# Need Information

Tags: software-installation

I am a designer i work on graphics, animation, ui/ux designs, web design and video editing, i have to use Adobe family (Photoshop. illustrator, premier pro, after effects and more other adobe software) and some other software, like Sketch, invision etc, which are related to my work.

What i need to know is that, kindly tell me that does your operating system is compatible for these software of not ? if yes then let me know how can i get the OS, and how can i get the software for this OS, and what will be the compete process?

Looking forward for your kind response.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Adobe family softwares does not work in linux by itself, but you can try installing it with emulators.
There are a few emulators for windows softwares such as Wine or CrossOver, that will allow you to install almost any window's software in linux (sometimes this has errors and lower performance, and in my own experience this option is way harder to do in ElementaryOS than in other linux distro).
Sadly this is the only way i know to make Windows software to work in Linux, otherwise you could try having ElementaryOS and Windows both installed in your computer

Answer (score 0):

The only option I found Adobe programs to work good into linux (including elementary os) is by running a virtual mashine with windows/macos which is ok if you have a really powerfull computer. Emulator versions like wine are really good for games, but with Adobe software they do not work well, also there are not so many versions that can run anyhow, but even if they did.. some functionalities are broken or missing. If I need to use Adobe programs, I use them on virtual mashines when the tasks are not so big and I need to provide some psd or ai file for example. But my computer is with Quad-Core Intel® Core™ i7-7700HQ CPU and 24GB of RAM, NVMe SSD and it is ok. If I run them on Windows, even on Hackintosh, the productivity will be much much better compared to the virtual mashine.

There are some linux alternatives. For video cut good linux option is kdenLive - this summer I produced a few hundred 2minutes videos of tandem flights, with template and branding of the paragliding club but I prefer the linux program then Premiere because actually I never did like Premiere. But if I have to compare kdenLive with Final Cut Pro.. mac application wins for sure! For vector graphics usually I use Inkscape, it's kind of difficult to achieve what I can do with Illustrator no matter that there are tools and functions which Illustrator misses and Gimp is my replacement of Photoshop with almost no downsides. But if you have a lot of experience with Adobe products - you will not gonna like the linux alternatives for sure because they work differently to what you have habits already, you will need to watch a lot of tutorial videos (there are soo many for free but it takes time) so if you plan to keep using the Adobe programs, I think that Linux (including elementary OS) is not good for you.